# Inserting data into MySQL database from Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables TBL1 and TBL2. TBL1 has 3 columns date, id, nSql. TBL2 has 3 columns date, custId, userId. 
I have 17 rows in TBL1 with id 1 to 17 (which will grow later). 
Each nSql has a SQL query in it. 
    For example nSql for id=1 is: "select date, pId as custId, tId as userId from TBL3"
    For example nSql for id=2 is: "select date, qId as custId, rId as userId from TBL4"
...
nSql result is always same 3 columns.

Below query only runs nSql for id =1. So, in TBL2 I have only output for nSql =1. I want result for all nSql. I want my query to run for all nSql
not just for id =1.

```
import MySQLdb

# Open database connection

con=MySQLdb.Connection(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="root", db="test")

# create a cursor object using cursor() method

cur=con.cursor()

selectStatement=("select nSql from TBL1") # I do not want to limit the number of id to select. For example, I do not want: select nSql from TBL1 where id in (1, 2, ..17)
cur.execute(selectStatement)
res=cur.fetchone()
nSql=res[0]
cur.execute(nSql)
reslt=cur.fetchall()
for row in reslt:
    date= row[0]
    custId= row[1]
    userId=row[2]
    insertStatement=("insert into TBL2( date, custId, userId) values ('%s', %d, %d)" % (date, custId, userId))
    cur.execute(insertStatement)
    con.commit()
```

Comment: You would need to fetch the results of `selectStatement` in a loop

Comment: I am new to python world. I would appreciate if you could show it in a code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already fetch the `nSql` result and loop over it.  You need to loop over both:

```
cur.execute(selectStatement)
res = cur.fetchall()
for outerrow in res:
    nSql = outerrow[0]
    cur.execute(nSql)
    # rest of your code
```

Comment: How can I say that if there is already data in TBL2 for that day, to remove that data and replace with new data?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing:

```
res=cur.fetchone()
nSql=res[0]
cur.execute(nSql)
```

It means you are taking only first ID (because you wrote `fetchone()`). In this case, ID equals to 1. You can keep calling `fetchall()` and by using loop, you can access all IDs.